# JPA2/Hibernate generated delete-statement missing a column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Using: Spring, JPA2.0, Hibernate, CrudRepository

So heres the relevant mapping-xml-parts..

Article-Entity:

```
<entity class="net.combase.cloud.data.pojo.ArticlePojo" metadata-complete="true" >
    <attributes>
    ///stuff following
        <element-collection name="prices" target-class="net.combase.cloud.data.pojo.PricePojo" fetch="LAZY" >
            <collection-table>
              <join-column name="article_pojo" referenced-column-name="id" unique="false" />
            </collection-table>
        </element-collection>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

Price-Embeddable

```
<embeddable class="net.combase.cloud.data.pojo.PricePojo" metadata-complete="true" access="PROPERTY" >
    <attributes>
        <basic name="validFrom" optional="false"><temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal></basic>
        <basic name="value" optional="false" />
        <many-to-one name="priceGroup" target-entity="net.combase.cloud.data.pojo.PriceGroupPojo" fetch="EAGER" optional="false"/>
        <many-to-one name="organizationalUnit" target-entity="net.combase.cloud.data.pojo.OrganizationalUnitPojo" fetch="EAGER" />
    </attributes>
</embeddable>
```

now If I save the article with a removed price.. I will get this statement in the logs:

```
Hibernate: delete from article_pojo_prices where article_pojo=? and price_group=? and valid_from=? and value=?
```

as you can see... the Org-Column is ignored...
so if I put optional=false on the org it would work... thing is...I need this column to be nullable.. 
any ideas anyone pleeaaase?

Have a nice day!

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?